# Array Element not getting removed in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, shell

This is my collection named STUDENTS

```
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "name" : "aimee Zank",
    "scores" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "exam",
            "score" : 1.46317973670502
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "quiz",
            "score" : 11.7827330995777
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 6.67617606065462
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 35.8740349954354
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run this, I am able to delete two array elements by HOMEWORK:

```
db.students.update(
  { '_id': 0  },
  { $pull: { scores: { type: 'homework' } } },
  { multi: true }
)
```

But, when I am trying to delete only one array by the actual score along with type=Homework,
it is not deleting that array element.
Can anyone please help, not getting anything in documentation, tried with single and double quote etc.

```
db.students.update(
  { '_id': 0  },
  { $pull: { scores: { type: 'homework', score: 6.67617606065462 } } },
  { multi: true }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it is not a Bug of any sort, I was using the IDE RoboMongo.
Mr RoboMongo rounded

```
score: 6.676176060654615
```

to

```
score: 6.67617606065462
```

I lost half a day on this.

Answer (score 2):

Although I couldn't reproduce it, it's generally not recommended to compare floating point numbers for equality. Instead you need to compare it to be more than expected value and less then expected value with some reasonable margin, e.g.

```
db.students.update(
  { '_id': 0  },
  { $pull: { scores: { type: 'homework', score: {$gte:6.67617606065461, $lte: 6.67617606065463 }} } },
  { multi: true }
)
```